# Android intercept SEND email event

Tags: android, email, send, intercept

Is there a way I can modify/change email after user press send button in email app so that before it is sent I can modify it and then send it ...

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry. This would be a massive privacy breach.

Comment: Yeah I know but ..Actually I have to send a form through the users email to another email ...When the user click submit the form should be sent without further user intervention